# Find the convolution between $ e^{-t} u(t) $ and $ e^{-2t} u(t-3)$

Tags: integration, convolution

Find the convolution between $ e^{-t} u(t) $ and $ e^{-2t} u(t-3)$

I have tried to solve it in the following manner. My answer does not match with the one given in the textbook. I am not sure if I am correct or not.

[image]

Solution:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Mathematica gives
$$
\texttt{Convolve[E^(-\[Tau])*UnitStep[\[Tau]],E^(-2*\[Tau])*UnitStep[\[Tau]-3],\[Tau],t]} = \left(e^{-(t+3)}-e^{-2 t}\right) u(t-3)
$$
and computing the convolution integral directly,
$$
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-\tau } e^{-2 (t-\tau )} u (\tau ) u (t-\tau -3) \, d\tau = \left(e^{-(t+3)}-e^{-2 t}\right) u(t-3).
$$

Answer (score 1):

The textbook answer is equivalent to your answer. Observe that $$y(t)=e^{-6}[e^{-(t-3)}u(t)-e^{-2(t-3)}]u(t-3)$$ vanishes if $t\leq 3$. But if $t$ is in this range, then $u(t)=1$. Hence the textbook answer is equivalent to

$$e^{-6}[e^{-(t-3)}-e^{-2(t-3)}]u(t-3)=(e^{-t-3}-e^{-2t})u(t-3),$$
the same as what you obtained.